# Xcode project warning with retina 4-inch Support

Tags: ios, xcode

My Deployment Target = 7.0

- I would put an image if i could but the warning deals with "deployment      Target" with in the "xcodeproj" it reads

  ```
   "Retina 4-inch Support
    Applications using Launch Screen Files and 
    targeting IOS 7.1 and earlier need to also
    include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog."
  ```

**My questions**

- What is this warning and do I have to worry about it?
- What Deployment Target would be best (this is my first app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: You must be using a LaunchImage in your app to show a "splash screen" [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW3).

That is the "old" way of doing it, the "new" way is to include these images under LaunchImage in Images.xcassets. The warning is just saying that if you include the old style launch images, then you should also include the images in the Asset Catalogue.

It won't stop you app running - it's more of a guideline, but seeing as you're learning, it's a good habit to get into.

As for deployment targets, it depends if you want to use iOS 8 only code, if not then iOS 7 is a good baseline...